# How to use "findBy" in an Entity with a Composite PK (Hibernate JPA)

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am learning with bootspring.

`findByDate(int date);` used to work until I've moved `int Date` into the inner class.

Now I can save new entries but I can't retrive them byDate

What do I need to change?

```
@Transactional
public interface ExpirationDAO extends JpaRepository<ExpirationDTO, Long> {

    public ExpirationDTO findByDate(int date);
}
```

and

```
@Embeddable
    public static class IdKey implements Serializable{
        @NotNull
        int date;
        @ManyToOne
        ProductDTO product;

        public IdKey(){
        }
         //setters and getters
    }
    @EmbeddedId
    private IdKey id;
    @NotNull
    int units;

    public ExpirationDTO(){     
    }
       //setters and getters
}
```

throws this exception:

```
org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property date found for type ExpirationDTO!
```

Comment: Which kind of attribute is your Date in your Database? Because you have `findByDate(String date)` with a String and in `IdKey` as `int`. Do you get any exception? And can you please be more specific what is not working.

Comment: you are right about the that. it should be int instead of String but that i'snt the issue. It was working fine with that mistake.

The exception is:
`org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property date found for type ExpirationDTO!`

Comment: Add the `int Date` to your `ExpirationDTO` Because your `findByDate` gives back an ExpirationDTO Object.

Comment: doesn't work
throws:
`org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity: app.model.data.ExpirationDTO column: date (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")` 
because date is repeated in the Composite key.

Comment: what happens if you add `insert="false" update="false"` to your date column?

Comment: i really don't know to insert that. 
but i did something that works but i don't know if it is the RIGHT way to do it.

it seems that `findByDate(int date);` uses the setters and getters for the mapping.
I've added them in ExpirationDTO to accses date in IdKey but i had to change stuff into static. i don't know if that is ok or wrong.

Comment: The problem is we do also not know what you need in your implementation. If the DTO is neceassary or why you need a embeddable class and so on. Just add more code in your question and describe your problem and your expected needs more clear.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You should include name of embedded key class in repository instead of Long.
Try this one (not tested):

```
public interface ExpirationDAO extends JpaRepository<ExpirationDTO, IdKey> {
    public List<ExpirationDTO> findByIdDate(int date);
}
```

There after `findBy` `Id` is yours `EmbeddedId` and `Date` is attribute of embeddable class. And one more thing: if you use only part of embedded key, you can't expect only one result...

Comment: Thanks! findByIdDate(int date); works! and yes, i'm not specting one result.
now I'm thinking it should be a relation ManyToMany. Many products have many expiration dates, and many expirations have diferents products.
Also @Patrick, thanks for your time too.

Comment: If you have more than one part of the composite key you'd like to search against you can join them together like `findByIdDateIdFooIdBar` source:  http://kevinmichaelcoy.com/blog/2021/02/25/spring-data-pageable-jpa-filter-query-with-3-of-4-parts-of-composite-key-via-a-query-method/

Answer (score 4):

You should include name of embedded key class in repository and also add an underscore (_)

Tested below:

```
public interface ExpirationDAO extends JpaRepository<ExpirationDTO, IdKey> {
    public List<ExpirationDTO> findByIdKey_Date(Date date);
}
```

Comment: Since the field is named "Id" in the ExpirationDTO class, the method should by findById..., not findByIdKey...